# The meaning of "posturing with the unseen"

Tags: meaning

> "...But Harvey, as I wrote his mistress from time to time, throve, and
> when he grew better, would play by himself grisly games of spying,
> walking up, hailing, and chasing another dog. From these he would
> break off of a sudden and return to his normal stiff gait, with the
> air of one who had forgotten some matter of life and death, which
> could be reached only by staring at me. I left him one evening
> **posturing with the unseen** on the lawn, and went inside to finish some letters for the post."

*"The Dog Hervey " by Rudyard Kipling*.
https://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/tale/the-dog-hervey.htm

I can't understand the meaning of "posturing with the unseen" in the article.

Answer (score 9):

This dog is playing games in which it pretends to be chasing another dog.  The other dog is imaginary.

"Posturing"  means placing itself in a particular pose, particularly it means "pretending to be something it is not" (pretending to be a tough dog?).  And the "unseen" is the imaginary dog.